# Problems with Sdk path or Gradle in Nativescript 8

Tags: nativescript

A while ago I was testing version 7 with success, but now with version 8, AVD cannot be installed separately from Android Studio and I see that it generates a different directory structure than Android/Sdk/build-tools had before.

Now the structure that Android Studio generates is by versions of Android/Sdk/build-tools/{latest, 30, 31,....}.

So, I don't know if the error I have is because I haven't generated the routes correctly in the $PATH or it's from Gradle.

I don't see anywhere in the Nativescript version 8 documentation how to do the paths and environment variables.

I also wanted to try with version 7 of Nativescript, but when I try with CLI 7 and do "create", Core 8 is installed. I don't know if there is a parameter or if I have to do it in another way.